# gcloud datastore emulator: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I just installed the Google cloud datastore emulator locally for testing my applications. I'm getting a weird error when starting it up. Google search didn't return any results.

I installed it with the following command:

```
gcloud components install cloud-datastore-emulator
```

Installation seemed successful.

Here's the output of starting it with `debug` verbosity:

```
❯ gcloud beta emulators datastore start --verbosity debug
DEBUG: Running [gcloud.beta.emulators.datastore.start] with arguments: [--verbosity: "debug"]
DEBUG: (gcloud.beta.emulators.datastore.start) [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
This may be due to network connectivity issues. Please check your network settings, and the status of the service you are trying to reach.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 787, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 759, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/emulators/datastore/start.py", line 69, in Run
    datastore_util.GetHostPort(), ipv6_enabled=socket.has_ipv6)
  File "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/emulators/datastore_util.py", line 162, in GetHostPort
    return util.GetHostPort(DATASTORE)
  File "/usr/local/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/command_lib/emulators/util.py", line 222, in GetHostPort
    if sock.connect_ex((host, port)) != 0:
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
gaierror: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.emulators.datastore.start) [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known
This may be due to network connectivity issues. Please check your network settings, and the status of the service you are trying to reach.
```

Any ideas of what is going on are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a quick test and installed Cloud Datastore with `$ gcloud components install cloud-datastore-emulator` and run `$ gcloud beta emulators datastore start --verbosity debug` without a problem.

What’s the output if you run `$ gcloud beta emulators datastore start` with no flags? 
Looks to be a connectivity issue. Have you tried forcing the host and port? Try running `$ gcloud beta emulators datastore start --verbosity debug --host-port 127.0.0.1:8080`